# Plotly Express px.line() parameter color_discrete_map not working correctly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

I'm trying to assign specific colors to different lines on my plotly line graph and when specifying key/color pairs using the color_discrete_map parameter I do not get the correct output. For example, the hex code I have used for the Mcdonal'ds attribute is a yellow but the final graph shows that line as a blue color.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("fastfood.csv")
df.drop(df[df["Year"] < 2018].index, inplace = True)
df["Percent Change"] = df.groupby("Corporation")["Total Revenue"].apply(lambda x: ((x-x.iloc[0]) / x.iloc[0]) * 100)

fig = px.line(df,
    x="Date",
    y="Percent Change",
    title="Fast Food Company Revenue Growth",
    render_mode="svg",
    color="Corporation",
    color_discrete_map={"Mcdonald's":"#FFFF00",
            "Wendy's": "#DD1438",
            "Burger King": "#F2A900",
            "Taco Bell": "#36399A",
            "KFC": "#f5d4b7"},
    width=800,
    height=600,
    )

fig.show()
```

Am I missing something here? Why are my colors from color_discrete_map all messed up?

I tried playing around with the color attributes a bit but they are always coming back as different than the hex value codes I specify.

Comment: I applied your code to the [example](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plots-on-date-axes) in the reference since there is no data for your question. Correctly the first ticker shows yellow. Is the version you are currently using the latest? Can you provide sample data to reproduce the defect?

Comment: It looks like you’re new to SO; welcome to the community! To get great answers quickly, it’s best to make your question reproducible. This includes things like the data you used. 
If you used a pandas data frame, extract the data with `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` and copy the output exactly as it appears. If you used base Python data structures, try `repr` (no import needed).